# Simple Leaflet.js Marker Placement

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, openstreetmap, projection

I'm using the [open source Leaflet.js library](https://leafletjs.com/) to create a simple map.

I'm trying to solve a specific problem though. Markers are tied to a specific lat/lng on a map, which makes sense, but I need to be able to make a marker have a fixed offset position from another marker, without it being tied to a lat/lng center.

So for example, the map may look like this:
[image: a leaflet.js map of two markers]

But when you zoom out, it'll look like this:
[image]

---

What I actually want is for the right marker to be a fixed offset away from the left marker, instead of being tied to a latlng, as such:
[image]

---

I've tried experimenting with [unproject](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-unproject) but I believe I'm going down the wrong path of how to handle this. It's unconventional what I'm doing but if anyone has any insight into how I could do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `project()` and `unproject()` methods to calculate position of second marker you can also listen to zoom events on the map and update the position of the second marker in order to keep the desired distance in pixels.

Have a look at the following example.

```js
var marker;
var pos = L.latLng(28.478226,-16.313488);
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView(pos, 13);
 
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);

L.marker(pos).addTo(mymap);
  
setLinkedMarkerAtDistance(180);
  
mymap.on('zoomstart', function() {
  if (marker) {
   mymap.removeLayer(marker);
  }
});
  
mymap.on('zoomend', function() {
  setLinkedMarkerAtDistance(180);
});

function setLinkedMarkerAtDistance(d) {
  var p = mymap.project(pos, mymap.getZoom());
  var p1 = p.add(L.point(d,0));
  var pos1 = mymap.unproject(p1, mymap.getZoom());
  if (marker) {
    marker.setLatLng(pos1).addTo(mymap);
  } else {
   marker = L.marker(pos1).addTo(mymap);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much @xomena. The solution seems elegant so far as I’m going through it. The reason I ask is because I’m attempting to place three image thumbnails to the right of a marker. I figured the best way to do this would be to use the `L.divIcon` class, basically creating a fancy marker with the `html` option. I opted for this because `ImageOverlay` seemed limiting in that I could not add extra html. Does this approach seem to make sense to you or would you handle this a different way?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me: you want to display some extra info (possibly looking similar to a normal Marker) next to a Marker A (with some pixels offset), and you try with another Marker B; but Marker B is tied to Lat/Lng coordinates instead of pixels offset, so you ask for help on how to use `unproject`.

To achieve your original objective, a Leaflet [DivIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#divicon) would [indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920454/simple-leaflet-js-marker-placement#comment92751402_52920872) have been a more appropriate solution: a part of the `<div>` would contain your actual Marker Icon, and another part would contain your extra info. That way, it always stays at the desired position, without having to compute any (un)projection and without any JS event listener involved:

[image: Screenshot map with Marker in DivIcon with extra info box]

```js
var paris = [48.86, 2.35];
var map = L.map('map').setView(paris, 11);

var divIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: `
    <img src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/images/marker-icon.png" />
    <div class="extra-info">
      Some extra info
    </div>
  `,
  className: 'my-div-icon',
  iconAnchor: [12, 41]
});

L.marker(paris, {
  icon: divIcon
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.extra-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 188px;
  bottom: -20px;
  min-width: 120px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-+ZaXMZ7sjFMiCigvm8WjllFy6g3aou3+GZngAtugLzrmPFKFK7yjSri0XnElvCTu/PrifAYQuxZTybAEkA8VOA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

An even more appropriate solution would have been to use a Leaflet [Tooltip](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tooltip), typically with your predefined [`offset`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tooltip-offset), [`permanent: true`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tooltip-permanent) option, a specific [`direction`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tooltip-direction) and custom styling (with `className`):

```js
var paris = [48.86, 2.35];
var map = L.map('map').setView(paris, 11);

L.marker(paris).bindTooltip('Some extra info', {
  offset: [188, 0],
  className: 'my-tooltip',
  permanent: true,
  direction: 'right',
  interactive: true
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.leaflet-tooltip.my-tooltip {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.leaflet-tooltip.my-tooltip::before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-+ZaXMZ7sjFMiCigvm8WjllFy6g3aou3+GZngAtugLzrmPFKFK7yjSri0XnElvCTu/PrifAYQuxZTybAEkA8VOA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Then if you *really* want your extra info to be styled and manipulated like a normal Leaflet Marker, another possible solution would be to use a custom Marker with modified [`iconAnchor`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#icon-iconanchor), to account for your desired pixel offset:

```js
var paris = [48.86, 2.35];
var map = L.map('map').setView(paris, 11);

var OffsetIcon = L.Icon.Default.extend({
  options: {
    // Subtract your desired offset.
    iconAnchor: [12 - 188, 41]
  }
});

L.marker(paris).addTo(map);
L.marker(paris, {
  icon: new OffsetIcon()
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-+ZaXMZ7sjFMiCigvm8WjllFy6g3aou3+GZngAtugLzrmPFKFK7yjSri0XnElvCTu/PrifAYQuxZTybAEkA8VOA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```