# Add custom buttons on a Leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

Is it possible to add some buttons on Leaflet map layer (Rectangle)?

For the moment I add a single button on the top-right (of bounds of it) as marker and customize it using css class style.

But now, I need to add multiple buttons. I can add multiple 'markers' but I need to calculate the coordinates of each of these (to distanziate each buttons).

Are there some others methods/plugins?

EDIT: I added a screenshot example about the current version.
[image]

Comment: Should your buttons be tied to locations?

Comment: @KoshVery I added a screenshot example of current version. I need to add others buttons next to orange button

Comment: It would be better to add a code snippet as a [mcve] instead of the screenshot.

Comment: Why to add necessarily a button? You can add an icon as you have done & listen to an event once clicked plus adding `cursor: pointer` to each one of the buttons.

Comment: @kboul Yes, but I need to understand how and where I can add this icon. In my current case it is easy because I use the upper/left and upper/right corners of layer bounds. But If I need to add an other button next to the orange button I need to specify the coordinates (because I use a custom icon on a marker). So, how far I have to distance these?  It there a methods simpler than this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920454/simple-leaflet-js-marker-placement/52938314#52938314